# Global flag to not start suspend function?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to start method `getFuelPrice` only if it not start before. To do this I use global flag `isStartGetFuelPrice`

smt like this:

```
for (currentPass in 0..10) {  
 // some code here  
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
   if (!isStartedGetFuelPrice) {
      currentCheck = getFuelPrice(currentCheck)
                       }
                                    }
}
```

on iteration 1 the method `getFuelPrice` start but on iteration 2 must not start. Function `getFuelPrice` must call ONLY ONCE.

and this:

```
suspend fun getFuelPrice(currentRecognizedCheck: Check): Check {

        isStartedGetFuelPrice = true
// some logic here
isStartedGetFuelPrice = false
        return currentRecognizedCheck
```

but I think that global flag is not good solution. Has any other better approach?

Comment: You want to call this function 11 times sequentially, waiting for the result each time? Are there other places in code where you call `getFuelPrice()` and also need those calls to wait their turn? If so, should that other function wait for it to be ready or just give up?

Comment: @Tenfour04 only in this place call getFuelPrice(). I want to call function getFuelPrice() only one time.

Comment: Then what is `for (currentPass in 0..10)` for?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Loop need for another stuff.

Comment: I don't understand. If you only want to call it one time, why don't you move it outside the loop? Or wrap it in `if (currentPass == 0){ }`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can't change code of loop. External code call many times method getFuelPrice. So as result I need to use global flag to avoid this. To call getFuelPrice only once.

Comment: So when some function calls `getFuelPrice` and it is already busy, do you want it to wait until done and then repeat the action, or should this other function give up?

Comment: @Tenfour04 if getFuelPrice was call then another call must not call anymore getFuelPrice. As result getFuelPrice will call ONLY ONCE. That exactly what I need.

Comment: OK, so it can only be called one time ever. I was confused because in your code above you set `isStartedGetFuelPrice` back to false so it can be called again.

Answer (score 1):

Using global mutable shared state is indeed not recommended for concurrent code.

You can try something like this, though:

```
data class Once(private val block: suspend () -> Unit) {
    private val ran = AtomicBoolean(false)
    suspend fun run() {
        if (ran.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
val once = Once { getFuelPrice() }
for (currentPass in 0..10) {  
    // some code here  
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
       once.run()
    }
}
```

You could also have `Once` that returns a value, but for that you'll need to use Kotlin `Mutex`:

```
data class Once<out T : Any>(private val block: suspend () -> T) {
    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private lateinit var r : T

    suspend fun run(): T {
        mutex.lock()
        if (!this::r.isInitialized) {
            r = block()
        }
        mutex.unlock()
        return r
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
suspend fun run(): T {
    return mutex.withLock {
        if (!this::r.isInitialized) {
            r = block()
        }
        r
    }
}
```

If you don't like mutexes, there's also another trick:

```
class Once<T>(block: suspend () -> T) {
    private val r = GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        block()
    }

    suspend fun run() = r.await()
}
```

Comment: Assuming `getFuelPrice` has to be a suspend function, you also need to mark `block` and `run()` as `suspend`.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin getFuelPrice must return my custom object Check